# How do I retrieve password policies of user from Windows AD/OpenLDAP server using php script?

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I need to retrieve password polices of AD/OpenLDAP users using php script.
I have all necessary details which are needed to connect to server, I'm not sure as which query filter should I be using in order to fetch password policy from LDAP servers.

Comment: This is more tricky than just using the right "query filter". And it's not the same for different LDAP server implementations. Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes that is right it may not be same for different LDAP servers, I want to write a generic script which can be used to fetch password policy details from LDAP servers but mainly OpenLDAP and Windows AD Server.
I'm able to get policy details from OpenLDAP server using pwdPolicy objectClass in filter but not sure if it will work on all the OpenLDAP servers.

Comment: @MichaelStröder How should i proceed?

Comment: @MichaelStröder I'm able to retrieve lockoutduration,lockoutobservationwindow,lockoutthreshold,maxpwdage,minpwdage,minpwdlength,pwdhistorylength these attributes by using (&(objectClass=domainDNS)(objectClass=domain)) this filter as these attributes are attached to the root dn.. Is this the same in case of all Windows ad servers?